# JavaScript-Change Navigation Style On Scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the active section to be highlighted when scrolling the page.

But i am getting error: "Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': The provided selector is empty."

Why? How to solve this?

js:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', event=>{
    let navigationLinks = document.querySelectorAll('nav ul li a');
    let fromTop = window.scrollY;

    navigationLinks.forEach(link=>{
        let section = document.querySelector(link.hash);
        if (section.offsetTop <=fromTop &&
            section.offsetTop + section.offsetHeight > fromTop
        ){
            link.classList.add('active');
        } else{link.classList.remove('active');}
    })
});
```

html:

```
<nav>
      <ul class="nav-links">
                <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
       </ul>
</nav>

<section>
   <div id="about"></div>
   <div id="contact"></div>
</section>
```

css:

```
nav a.active{
    color: darkcyan;
    border-bottom: 2px solid darkgoldenrod;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you give is caused by the first link.

The href is `#` so the `link.hash` property will be `""`

Both `document.querySelector("")` and `document.querySelector("#")` raise an error.
The solution is to add a check if the hash is not empty.

```
if (link.hash != "" && link.hash != "#") {
```

**Note** that the `Home` link will always stay active since it doesn't have a corresponding `<div id="home">` element

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', event => {
  let navigationLinks = document.querySelectorAll('nav ul li a');
  let fromTop = window.scrollY;

  navigationLinks.forEach(link => {
    if (link.hash != "" && link.hash != "#") {
      let section = document.querySelector(link.hash);
      if (section.offsetTop <= fromTop &&
        section.offsetTop + section.offsetHeight > fromTop
      ) {
        link.classList.add('active');
      } else {
        link.classList.remove('active');
      }
    }

  })
});
```

```css
nav a.active {
  color: darkcyan;
  border-bottom: 2px solid darkgoldenrod;
}


/* for demonstration purposes */

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

#about,
#contact {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="nav-links">
    <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<section>
  <div id="about">About</div>
  <div id="contact">Contact</div>
</section>
```